# Error when launching AVD in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

> HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. emulator: WARNING:
>   UpdateCheck: Failure: Error audio: Failed to create voice
>   `goldfish_audio_in' qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input
>   failed emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
>   emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
>   emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
>   [8476]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed to process
>   .ini file C:\Users\MDG.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
>   emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error emulator: WARNING:
>   UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current
>   version '25.2.5-3567187')

I'm new to Android studio and I'm unable to fix the above error .
I have installed HAXM, I have set the path variables for android SDK and I have set the RAM below 1GB.

I have a computer that is a 64-bit system that runs Windows 10. I have tried both the Lollipop 22 x86_64 and Lollipop 22 x86 System Images and they both fail.

I cannot figure out what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "[What this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/about)" and "[How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" before asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the configuration of your emulator. You can still use the same emulator to run on RAM size of 1GB by the below command:

```
$ emulator @<avd_name> -memory <1024 - RAM size in MB>
```

NOTE: run the above command in the SDK folder or the SDK/tools folder. and RAM value specified will overrides the AVD setting.

Now in case you are running multiple emulators be aware of the HAXM maximum RAM configuration which it can provide to your emulator. else the emulator whichever is launched later will exit/crash cuz of RAM issues.
Good luck!